# stackoverflow.com, automated cloning to other languages (chinese: helplib.com/qa)

Tags: discussion, scraping

I previously answered a question with a function from my personal JS library. And out of laziness used google to look it up (for work) the rather unique function name **simpleRecusiveDeepEqual** and its resulting stackoverflow clones. (as oppose to digging through my library)

However what stood out most, was after "google deduplication of results". It was only left my original answer, and surprisingly its clone. In Chinese.

Most impressively, it translated only the text, and not the code snippets.

**Original:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703135/793842

**Chinese:** http://www.helplib.com/qa/117563

My point here **is not** regarding SCRAPER, as I am unable to verify attribution. Especially since my Chinese, despite being part of my heritage is effectively zero. And i am not going to point fingers if google failed the translate. (see: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)).

But rather whats the opinion of having such cloned sites in other languages, assuming proper attribution. Especially for those of us here who does not have English as a main language.

In all honesty this sounds like a cool hobby project for myself personally. [(on SO database dumps)](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) For there maybe value for others who do not even speak english (not just Chinese). As horrible as google translate can be.

**PS:** if someone with decent Chinese, can verify if its a scraper, please report it.

Comment: *"whats the opinion of having such cloned sites in other languages, assuming proper attribution"* - as long as they follow [the TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal), they can do whatever they like!

Comment: I find these sites really annoying. Some time ago there was a site like this auto-translating SO questions to German and this site managed to get better google ranking than SO itself. The problem was that the translation was, even though very funny, mostly not understandable. Further they did give credit to SO but missed to add a direct link to the specific question... On the other hand, if translation is good enough, I think these sites can be usefull for people with bad English skills.

Comment: There is 0 attribution on that page. In fact, the only links pointing back to SO on that website are the ones scraped from the comments/answers.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva thanks, i have filled up the official reporting / contact form.